# Nodejs: Import local modules during development

Tags: node.js, module

I'm working on a fairly large project where our code is split into separate modules. (Mostly because we're re-using this part over different services)

This becomes a problem when we're working across these different modules, it's a bit annoying to constantly push changes to github and run an `npm install` again in order to get these into a different project.

Is there a way to overwrite the location of a node module when in development? Basically while developing I just want to import the module from my local filesystem, while on production it want it to be imported from the git source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `npm link` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

This will allow you to create a direct link in your `node_modules` to a local version of your modules.